# Gree iOS Achievements show Dashboard

Tags: ios, xcode, gree

how to show Achievements in Gree in iOS.
Before in OpenFeint i use this:

```
[OpenFeint launchDashboardWithAchievementsPage];
```

but in Gree i can't find any similar to this method.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think you have travelled far with GREE, can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696287/gree-integration-endup-with-errors.