# GREE Integration endup with Errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gree

I integrated GREE in an iOS application(demo) and after a day long hard work the code was good enough to go, that executed properly and produced some UI response but, pity that was no worthy, check:

[image]

Also I have something in my console;

```
 2012-12-04 09:52:22.721 GreeHelloSample[1295:1bb03] GreeJSAbstractStateCommand:name must be overloaded in subclasses.
 2012-12-04 09:52:22.724 GreeHelloSample[1295:1bb03] GreeJSAsyncCommand:name must be overloaded in subclasses.
 2012-12-04 09:52:22.725 GreeHelloSample[1295:1bb03] GreeJSLoadAsynchronousCommand:name must be overloaded in subclasses.
 2012-12-04 09:52:22.997 GreeHelloSample[1295:1bb03] [Gree][GreePlatform.m:381]  Initialized Gree Platform SDK 3.4.0 (Build release/v3.4.0_public_189)
 2012-12-04 09:52:24.589 GreeHelloSample[1295:1bb03] didLogoutUser
 2012-12-04 09:52:25.003 GreeHelloSample[1295:1bb03] greePlatformWillShowModalView
```

But I am tired and unable to track **What went wrong,** now? So, help me.

## EDIT 1:

Here is All related code I wrote:

## .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GreePlatform.h"
#import "GreePlatformSettings.h"

#define kGreeApplicationID  @"XXXXX"
#define kGreeConsumerKey    @"XXXXXXXXXXXX"
#define kGreeConsumerSecret @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

@class GHSViewController;
@interface GHSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, GreePlatformDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) GHSViewController *viewController;

@end
```

## .m

```
#import "GHSAppDelegate.h"
#import "GHSViewController.h"

@implementation GHSAppDelegate

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[GHSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GHSViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:GreeDevelopmentModeSandbox, GreeSettingDevelopmentMode, nil];

    [GreePlatform initializeWithApplicationId:kGreeApplicationID
                                  consumerKey:kGreeConsumerKey
                               consumerSecret:kGreeConsumerSecret
                                     settings:settings
                                     delegate:self];
    [GreePlatform handleLaunchOptions:launchOptions application:application];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    [GreePlatform shutdown];
}

#pragma mark - GreePlatformDelegate
/**
 * Sent to the receiver when Gree will show a modal view (dashboard, login dialogs,
 * etc.) that will interrupt your application.
 * @note It is recommended that you suspend your application logic here.
 */
-(void)greePlatformWillShowModalView:(GreePlatform*)platform{
    NSLog(@"greePlatformWillShowModalView");
}
/**
 * Sent to the receiver when Gree has dismissed a modal view (dashboard, login dialogs,
 * etc.) that was interrupting your application.
 * @note It is recommended that you resume your application logic here.
 */
-(void)greePlatformDidDismissModalView:(GreePlatform*)platform{
    NSLog(@"greePlatformDidDismissModalView");
}
/**
 * Sent to the receiver when your application's user logs in to the Gree Platform.
 */
-(void)greePlatform:(GreePlatform*)platform didLoginUser:(GreeUser*)localUser{
    NSLog(@"didLoginUser");
}
/**
 * Sent to the receiver when your application's user logs out of the Gree Platform.
 */
-(void)greePlatform:(GreePlatform*)platform didLogoutUser:(GreeUser*)localUser{
        NSLog(@"didLogoutUser");
}
/**
 @brief Notifies the parameter received when an application starts.
 @param params Parameter received when an application starts.
 */
-(void)greePlatformParamsReceived:(NSDictionary*)params{
       NSLog(@"greePlatformParamsReceived");
}
```

Comment: You will probably want to include some of your code where you suspect it is going wrong. This is pretty ambiguous. However, it seems your not setting up an implementation of one of those classes properly, by not overloading the name variable. as a guess.

Comment: Probably this'll make it clear..

Comment: Hmm i cannot see anything obvious. I'm not a Gree expert at all. I wonder if there is some library you are not linking to perhaps. Or is Gree trying to connect to the internet but the connection is failing or offline. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go!

I have made one silly mistake to suffer this. Actually I was using Production (Gree Application) ID, for executing my application in sand box. Although Gree Provide different Sandbox ID to run Application in Sandbox environment. Rest of the things are Okay thanks to Gree framework SDK, and specially **Showcase***(sample application).